# Are there any OS X equivalents to `hcitool`?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I'd like to write some quick scripts to play with bluetooth devices (scan etc…), for the Mac. Under linux I'd probably use `hcitool`, or the python bluez library.

What tools are there for the Mac?

Answer (score 4):

`hcitool` is a command that comes with [BlueZ](http://www.bluez.org/), which is specific to the Linux kernel.

Unfortunately, I don't have Mac OSX, so I can't test this, but as far as I know, [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) shares a lot with BSD, so they both use [Netgraph framework](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netgraph&sektion=4) for bluetooth drivers. There's some information on how to use [Bluetooth in FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/network-bluetooth.html), I think they might be helpful, at least as a starting point. The `hcitool` equivalent in FreeBSD is [`hccontrol`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hccontrol).

Answer (score 1):

[blueutil](https://github.com/toy/blueutil) is a good alternative for hcitool.

It supports a lot of options like power, discoverable, inquire, list, connect and so on.

You can take a look at the manual and use it.

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Anands-MacBook-Air.local 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: ... arm64

$ blueutil
Power: 1
Discoverable: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`blueutil` mentioned does not have a scan capability which the OP requested.

> The underlying IOBluetoothDevice API can only get the RSSI from connected devices.

Reference:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/346263/get-list-of-discoverable-bt-devices-with-power-rssi-and-mac-address

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bluetool`

```bash
$  bluetool

Welcome to BlueTool... Rev 6.0

bluetool-> ?
BlueTool Help
  ?                : Print out all commands and some help.
  autobaud         : Run automatic baud rate on the selected device.
  device           : Select the device to communicate over.
  hci              : Send an HCI command to the Bluetooth device.
  aci              : ACI specific operations.
  bcm              : Broadcom specific operations.
  msleep           : Sleep the caller for the given number of milliseconds
  spam             : Spam data to the UART
  if               : if <test> ? a : b
  true             : true
  false            : false
  echo             : echo
  power            : Power on/off the Bluetooth device.
  reset            : Reset on/off/pulse the Bluetooth device.
  wake             : Wake on/off/pulse the Bluetooth device.
Give any commands '-h' for more details.
bluetool->
```